# Flash Player + Google Chrome - Accessibility keyboard control issue

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, accessibility, flash

To comply with some Accessibility guidelines, my latest project (AS3 Flash based project) has to have both keyboard & mouse control. For the keyboard control i have created a multi-box system which allows users to tab between each box to control the in-game character. Whilst you can use the TAB key to do this, i also wanted the user to use the up/down arrow keys.

I've implemented this system & tested across all modern browsers, however in Google Chrome's latest build (23.0.1271.95) I have found that whilst the tabbing works fine through the TAB key, the arrow key control does not.

The down key works through a couple of the objects, but then resets back to the first object. The up key does nothing.

It's quite a strange issue, has anyone seen anything like it before? I don't think there is anything i can do through AS3 but maybe there's something like a flash object paramater (seamlesstabbing etc) i can set through HTML that i don't know of?

I've got a bad feeling it's a problem with Google Chrome's flash player, hopefully not!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While trying to comply with accessibility guidelines, you've to do your best to comply with WCAG 2.0 for example but you don't have to solve the problems browsers have with plugins, AT and such. That's an UAAG problem. If you can solve it with a simple solution, fine but if not then chances are that keyboard users aren't using Chrome on that OS; they'll be using Firefox or a modern IE as the problem exists with every site they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime anyone reports a problem with Flash that only happens in Chrome, I immediately assume it is the buggy "Pepper Flash" player that Chrome started using by default.

Pepper Flash is Adobe/Google's effort to keep the Flash plugin alive on linux platforms. However, it is also used on other OS's by default. It is new and apparently has many issues. I wouldn't be surprised if this was another one.

To confirm, disable Pepper Flash by going here (look for the Flash plugin that has "pepper" in the name/path):

chrome://plugins

You likely have the regular Flash plugin installed, so merely disabling Pepper Flash should suffice. However, Chrome will likely update itself and re-enable it at some point. If you don't have the regular "netscape style" Flash plugin, you can download it from Adobe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what i thought it would be as well. Do you know if they've recently updated their Pepper Flash? I seem to be noticing a lot more inconsistencies recently.

Comment: Flash 11.5 came out at the end of November. I find that Pepper Flash issues seem to come and go (mostly come) with each release.